# ServiceStack FallbackRoute failing with upgraded ServiceStack version

Tags: c#, servicestack

We upgraded our C# web services from ServiceStack V4.0.31 to V5.1.0. We're using the following packages in a linux environment with a monodevelop runtime.

```
  <package id="ServiceStack" version="5.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="ServiceStack.Client" version="5.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="ServiceStack.Common" version="5.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="ServiceStack.Interfaces" version="5.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="ServiceStack.Redis" version="5.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="ServiceStack.Text" version="5.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
```

After upgrading we are now having problems when processing some of our client requests. Our request DTO contains several routes but the following one always fails.

```
[FallbackRoute("/{Path*}")]
public class S3Request : IRequiresRequestStream {
        public Stream RequestStream { get; set; }
}
```

This route is invoked when a client issues a

```
GET http://endpoint:1310/name/clients/C1/sites/G1
```

(the port and route don't matter, just examples). We’re getting a 400 Bad Request with the following error response.

```
{
  "ResponseStatus": {
    "ErrorCode": "ArgumentException",
    "Message": "Could not find property Path on S3Request",
    "StackTrace": "  at ServiceStack.Host.RestPath.CreateRequest (System.String pathInfo, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue] queryStringAndFormData, System.Object fromInstance) [0x000c9] in <629ec152372546cf812fe4a698c7a784>:0 \n  at ServiceStack.Host.RestHandler.CreateRequest (ServiceStack.Web.IRequest httpReq, ServiceStack.Web.IRestPath restPath, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue] requestParams, System.Object requestDto) [0x0001e] in <629ec152372546cf812fe4a698c7a784>:0 \n  at ServiceStack.Host.ServiceController+<>c__DisplayClass26_0.<RegisterService>b__0 (ServiceStack.Web.IRequest req) [0x00035] in <629ec152372546cf812fe4a698c7a784>:0 \n  at ServiceStack.Host.Handlers.ServiceStackHandlerBase.GetCustomRequestFromBinder (ServiceStack.Web.IRequest httpReq, System.Type requestType) [0x00018] in <629ec152372546cf812fe4a698c7a784>:0 \n  at ServiceStack.Host.RestHandler.CreateRequestAsync (ServiceStack.Web.IRequest httpReq, ServiceStack.Web.IRestPath restPath) [0x00017] in <629ec152372546cf812fe4a698c7a784>:0 \n  at ServiceStack.Host.RestHandler+<ProcessRequestAsync>d__14.MoveNext () [0x00125] in <629ec152372546cf812fe4a698c7a784>:0 "
  }
}
```

The exception is thrown method ServiceStack.Host.RestPath.CreateRequest(…) in the following area of the code

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.TotalComponentsCount; i++) {
        string text = this.variablesNames [i];
        string key;
        if (text == null) {
                num++;
        } else if (!this.propertyNamesMap.TryGetValue (text.ToLower (), out key)) {
                if (!StringExtensions.EqualsIgnoreCase (Keywords.Ignore, text)) {
                        throw new ArgumentException ("Could not find property " + text + " on " + UrlExtensions.GetOperationName (this.RequestType));
                }
```

It appears that the CreateRequest method expects the propertyNamesMap to have an entry for the route but it’s not there. We’re wondering if the V5.1.0 API requires us to perform some sort of path registration logic that was not necessary in V4.0.31?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your DTO is missing the `Path` property on the Request DTO, every variable on the Route except `{ignore}` needs to match a property on the Request DTO.

Comment: For years I had the same construct without the Path property and it worked prior to  the V5 upgrade. Must be a change in V5! Thanks for the answer, it works.